# Publishing a Self-contained Console app fails

Tags: .net-core

I installed the `.NET SDK 2.1.301-win-x64.exe` and afterwards updated all the nuget packages to `2.1.1`.

In my WebApp I have the Nuget Package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.1` and `Microsft.NETCore.App 2.1.0`. In the Nuget Window I see that there's also the Version 2.1.1, but I can't select it (Blocked by Project)

Same story in my Console App: `Microsft.NETCore.App 2.1.0`

My first question: Is here already something wrong? Or is this expected behavior?

If I build the WebApp as self contained App, that works well.

If I biuld the Console App as self contained App (Self-contained / win-x64). I get the follwoing Error:

> The project was restored using Microsoft.NETCore.App version 2.1.1,
>   but with current settings, version 2.1.0 would be used instead.  To
>   resolve this issue, make sure the same settings are used for restore
>   and for subsequent operations such as build or publish.  Typically
>   this issue can occur if the RuntimeIdentifier property is set during
>   build or publish but not during restore."

The source of this error is a referenced project.

What do I do wrong? Let me know if you need additional information, then I will  add it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a known issue for the moment. In your referenced project's csproj file, set the `TargetLatestRuntimePatch` property:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This only happens when a .NET Core application references another .NET Core application and self-contained roll-forward only partially kicks in during publish.

For portable applications, it is enough to target 2.1.0 version of `Microsoft.NETCore.App` and when run on a target machine, the latest patch available on the machine will be used automatically. In recent tooling, a change was made so that the tooling would use the latest known patch version for self-contained applications so you automatically bundle the latest patch release with your application. However, this doesn't flow over project-to-project references.

See [Self-contained deployment runtime roll forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/runtime-patch-selection?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999) for more information.