# VSO Build Pipeline's Nuget Restore Failed

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, nuget-package, azure-pipelines

The Nuget Restore from VSO's build pipeline failed due to some nuget packages that are not compatible with `netcoreapp2.1`. However, when I looked through all the csproj files in the solution, none of the csproj files have these nuget packages. I might have installed these before but right now it's definitely not here.

[image]

Here's the csproj file that is mentioned in the error message.

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" Version="5.2.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Here's the Nuget.Config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Please advise how to fix this issue.

**EDIT=====================================================**

After removing the nuget package from `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi`, the `NugetRestore` passed, but `Build solution` failed. It shows a different error

> ### [error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.104\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(208,5):
>
> Error NETSDK1004: Assets file
> 'd:\agentwrok\18\s....\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a
> NuGet package restore to generate this file.

This is the configuration for Build Solution

[image]
Any advice on the next step?

Comment: You tagged aspnetcore but you are using standard version https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi. why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> VSO Build Pipeline's Nuget Restore Failed

Just like Volodymyr commented, you should not use the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` for the .net core project. That is because this package is targeted at .NETFramework, not .NET Core/.NETStandard. It is not compatible with .NET Core.

When you check the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` on [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/), you will notice that this package has a dependency on `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost`, which only targets the .NET Framework:

[image]

[image]

And the sub-dependency [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/) of the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost` also only targets the .NET Framework:

[image]

So, the reason for this issue is that the package `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` and its dependencies are not compatible with .NET Core framework.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I removed this nuget package but it is giving me a different error: `Assets file: ..\..\obj\prohect.assets.json` not found

Comment: @WWpana, Check the solution here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51642172/the-project-was-restored-using-microsoft-netcore-app-version-2-1-0-but-with-cur/51644988#51644988

Comment: @WWpana, Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: yes it worked. thanks. Will comment again if it fails again.